# AWS s3 upload api call returning 411 status

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, content-length, http-status-code-411

I have been trying to perform AWS s3 rest api call to upload document to s3 bucket. The document is in the form of a byte array.

```
PUT /Test.pdf HTTP/1.1
Host: mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com
Authorization: **********
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Length: 5039151
x-amz-content-sha256: STREAMING-AWS4-HMAC-SHA256-PAYLOAD
x-amz-date: 20180301T055442Z
```

When we perform the api call, it gives the response status 411 i.e Length Required. We have already added the Content-Length header with the byte array length as value. But still the issue is repeating. Please help to resolve the issue.

Comment: With `STREAMING-AWS4-HMAC-SHA256-PAYLOAD`, `Content-Length` isn't the size if the object itself... It's the object plus the overhead, and `Content-Encoding: aws-chunked` is expected.  Are you really using the proprietary chunked upload API?

Comment: No I am not using the chunked upload AP. How to calculate the correct `Content-Length`?

Comment: `STREAMING-AWS4-HMAC-SHA256-PAYLOAD` is only applicable to the chunked API.  You should use the hex-encoded sha256 of the body, or the string `UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD` for the `x-amz-content-sha256` header.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-auth-using-authorization-header.html  Using the actual hash is preferred, because this provides integrity checking of the upload body against bit-level corruption in transit -- rare, but possible.

Comment: Thank you so much. Adding `UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD` as `x-amz-content-sha256` header value resolved the issue. If you could add this as the answer I will set it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x-amz-content-sha256: STREAMING-AWS4-HMAC-SHA256-PAYLOAD` is only used with the non-standards-based [chunk upload API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-streaming.html).  This is a custom encoding that allows you to write chunks of data to the wire.  This is not the same thing as the [Multipart Upload API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html), and is not the same thing as `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` (which S3 doesn't support for uploads).

It's not clear why this would result in `411 Length Required` but the error suggests that S3 is not happy with the format of the upload.

For a standard `PUT` upload, `x-amz-content-sha256` must be set to the hex-encoded SHA-256 hash of the request body, or the string `UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD`.  The former is recommended, because it provides an integrity check. If for any reason your data were to become corrupted on the wire in a way that TCP failed to detect, S3 would automatically reject the corrupt upload and not create the object.

See also https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-auth-using-authorization-header.html